# How do I install opkg installer on a system that doesn't have it

Tags: software-installation

The system I am using has no package installer in the root fs image.  How do I install opkg itself?  I can't find a link to the x86 binaries.

Comment: What unix variant is that? How did you install your system?

Answer (score 1):

It probably doesn't exist.

According to [its website](http://code.google.com/p/opkg/), `opkg` is a package manager aimed specifically towards embedded systems.  If you've installed a flavor of linux to your desktop PC, said flavor will have come with a package manager of its own.

Without knowing which distribution or version of linux you installed, it's very hard to be more specific; all I can suggest is looking at the website of whatever distribution you installed.

Answer (score 0):

There aren't x86 binaries, because it's really aimed at embedded devices and the like. You'll have to compile the source yourself: http://code.google.com/p/opkg/source/browse/

It does beg the question though... If it's an x86 machine, why not just use apt/dpkg?

Comment: The choice between `dpkg`, `opkg`, `rpm`, `pkg_add`, etc, has nothing to do with the CPU type and everything to do with the distribution.